# Is it possible to combine a facebook page and a website in the social graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Facebook has "pages" for many things, like people, companies, etc. But it also has this open graph protocol. My company already has a web site, and we also have a facebook page (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/company)

People can "like" either one. We use a like iframe on the company website that refers to the website URL. I'd like to know if they can be connected such that when someone likes our facebook page, they really like our company's web site.

Or are these always going to be considered two different things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on puffpio's answer, you can have a like button for your existing page on you website by using the existing page's facebook url as the href parameter.

It is essential that you do not put a like button to your url if you do not want your likes split between the two. In this scenario there is no reason to have an open graph object for your page other than to provide correct data when a user shares your url in their feed. It's important to note that these shares also count towards the counter on the like button and as far as I know there is no way to recover them.

You can also use this url as your og:url tag however this will cause the linter to throw errors since the domains do not match.

Comment: Interesting. If I use the og:url tag on our web site, will this cause shared links to our web site like our facebook page instead?  I guess that would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

No. Page and website is something different and you can't force user to like both

Answer (score 1):

They are different things, but a workaround is that the like button on the company's website can be a like button for their page on Facebook with a caveat like 'Like us on Facebook' or something